# What are the easiest counterexamples to Serre-Lang over non-algebraically closed fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$. Let $X\to A$ be a finite etale morphism with $X$ a connected (smooth projective) variety over $k$.

Then, choosing a base point in $X(\overline{k})$, Serre-Lang's theorem says that $X_{\overline{k}}$ is an abelian variety and $X_{\overline{k}}\to A_{\overline{k}}$ is an isogeny.

I presume this statement fails when $k$ is not algebraically closed, because there might not be any $k$-rational point.

What are the "easiest" **explicit** counterexamples to Serre-Lang's theorem for non-algebraically closed fields $k$?

One idea was to take a $2$-torsion point $P\in A(L)\setminus A(k)$ of an abelian variety $A$, and then show that the dual of the natural $2$-isogeny $A_L\to A_L/<p>$ descends to $k$.

Comment: Something like $y^2=125x^4-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ mapping to $y^2=x^3-x$ by $(x,y) \mapsto (5x^2,xy)$. You might want to look at Silverman AEC X.3.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but if $A$ is an abelian variety over $k$, and $k'/k$ is any finite separable extension, then $A \times_{Spec(k)} Spec(k') \rightarrow A$ is a finite etale morphism from a connected smooth projective scheme over $k$. But $A \times_{Spec(k)} Spec(k')$ has no $k$-points because there are no maps $Spec(k) \rightarrow Spec(k')$. To give an "explicit example" just write down your favorite elliptic curve in place of A, and take, say, $k' = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2), k = \mathbb Q$.